# How to avoid ajc changing anonymous class static modifier on weaving?

Tags: java, akka, aspectj

I'm trying to integrate AspectJ to existing project. After weaving anonymous static classes becomes non-static.
For example this code:

```
public class StaticCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(Modifier.isStatic(getClass().getModifiers()));
            }
        }.run();
    }
}
```

outputs "true" without weaving and "false" with it.

The problem is that object created this way is passed to 3rd party code and this check is performed there.

Moving anonymous class to static inner class solves the problem but it's not desirable because such construction is heavily used in a project.

I'm using aspectj version 1.8.2 via aspectj-maven plugin with java 1.7.
3rd party framework is typesafe akka, and this is Props.create(Creator) actor creating construction.

So is there any way to avoid such aspectj behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not actually the weaving process that is losing the setting.  I investigated something like this recently under AspectJ bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=441741

In investigating that I discovered a piece of the java spec which appears to apply here which said "An anonymous class is always an inner class; it is never static."

Javac marks these things as static.  The Eclipse Compiler for Java (which AspectJ is using internally) does not mark it as static. If you compile and run your sample code in eclipse and it will print false. So it isn't the weaving, it is the compiler doing it.

As a workaround you could compile it with javac and then binary weave it with ajc - that will preserve the 'true' modifier.

I'm not sure the setting of this flag is something that should be relied upon.